# Go []string to C char**

Tags: c, types, go

I started trying to integrate some C libraries into my Go code for a project using cgo and have come across a problem.

In one of the C functions I need to pass argv to a function call. In C argv is a pointer to an array of char strings (K&R C, §5.10) and I need to convert from a slice of strings to a char**.

I have had a good look, high and low for any information on how to do variable type conversions from Go to C but there appears to be next to no documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/pQueMFdY0mk)?

Comment: Hi, I hadn't seen that so thank you. I understand a little more about type conversion having read that. It does appear to work with a few modifications however, namely manually calling `C.freeCharArray` manually when you have no need of argv, instead of defering it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to create the array yourself.  Something like this should do:

```
argv := make([]*C.char, len(args))
for i, s := range args {
    cs := C.CString(s)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
    argv[i] = cs
}
C.foo(&argv[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've wrapped that up in a function and it appears to have some problems. The first line produces an error `gm.go:73:25: expected operand, found ']'` and when removing this we run into further problems as you cannot make _Ctype_char and it appears you cannot reference an index of a _Ctype_char

Comment: Sorry, I've had my head buried in some C++ today and made a typo in the syntax -- the edit should fix it.  You may need to adjust the code a bit if you want to put this in a helper function: if the `defer` calls trigger before you make the C call, you'll be passing in freed memory.

Comment: Thats alright I keep on using PHP function names in Go! That appears to have sorted it out and I have turned it into a helper function with the main function cleaning things up with deferreds.